# Do Animagi in Harry Potter gain the magical abilities of the animal they transform into?

Tags: harry-potter, animagi

I'm curious about the extent of magical abilities that Animagi possess when they transform into various animals in the Harry Potter universe. While reading the series, I came across instances where certain animals, such as phoenixes and basilisks, have extraordinary magical powers. This got me wondering if Animagi are able to harness these abilities when they take on the form of such animals.

For example, we know that phoenixes have the ability to rejuvenate and heal with their tears, as well as lift heavy objects effortlessly. Would an Animagus who transforms into a phoenix be able to acquire these powers?

Similarly, basilisks are known to possess lethal venom and the ability to kill with their gaze. If an Animagus were to turn into a basilisk, would they gain these dangerous abilities as well?

I understand that Animagi are primarily wizards or witches who have the skill to transform into animals, but it's unclear whether they inherit the magical attributes of the animals they become. Can someone shed some light on this topic and provide insights from canon sources or official statements by J.K. Rowling herself? Additionally, if there are any specific limitations or variations among Animagi that affect their ability to acquire animal powers, please share that information as well.

Comment: Is there any indication that it's even possible for an Animagus to transform into a specifcially magical animal? AFAICT the only examples we see are standard cats, dogs, rats, etc.

Comment: @DanielRoseman While there is no definitive evidence in the canon to support the notion that an Animagus can be a magical creature, it is equally plausible that they could be. The absence of explicit information leaves room for speculation in both directions.

Comment: @FukaiMizumi, we (generally) don’t deal in speculation here.

Comment: J. K. Rowling stated that your patronus is likely the animal you will become when you are an Animagi.

Comment: @FukaiMizumi When did she state that?

Comment: I don't know if or where it was stated explicitly, but it is implied by Professor McGonnagal (cat Animagus and Patronus both).

Comment: @tsc_chazz And also Harry's father - he was a stag when he transformed, and he had the stag patronus as well (source: Dumbledore and Lupin).

Comment: I can't find anyone transforming into a magical animal in the books. The only one I can find with a magical patronus, on the other hand, is Dumbledore. So (theoretically) he would be a phoenix animagus, but he doesn't transform in the books. It isn't mentioned if he is a registered animagus either.

Comment: @FukaiMizumi in book 3 it sounds more like you choose yourself what animal you want to become when transforming into an animagus. Lupin talks about how Sirius and James transformed in big animals to be able to hold a werewolf back. Though I think often animagi will chose an animal that is their "spirit animal" which is also your patronus.

Comment: I don't think the animagus and patronus are matched, because your patronus can change over the course of your life but your animagus form cannot.